# Xcode 4.1+ Autolayout checkbox missing

Tags: xcode

I am trying to enable autolayout for an iOS project but cannot find the checkbox in the info panel. I know it's supposed to be under the versioning section and above Localization. I also see that the documentation says:

> Note: Auto Layout is available only in Mac OS X v10.7 Lion and later. If you are running Xcode 4 in Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard, Auto Layout is not available.

from:
http://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html

I'm on Lion and running Xcode 4.2 and the checkbox is not showing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did I miss something - it's for OS X 10.7 only right now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto Layout is implemented in AppKit in 10.7, so 10.7 is required to develop and to run.  It isn't in iOS 4 or 5.

Comment: I must have missed that tidbit at WWDC. So the important note here is that it only works for OSX projects. Thanks guys!